# Removing all BOMs from file with multiple BOMs

Tags: python, byte-order-mark

I have a text file containing multiple lines beginning with a byte order mark. Passing `encoding='utf-8-sig'` to `open` removes the BOM at the start of the file but all subsequent BOMs remain. Is there a more correct way to remove these than this:

```
import codecs

filepath = 'foo.txt'
bom_len = len(codecs.BOM_UTF8)

def remove_bom(s):
    s = str.encode(s)

    if codecs.BOM_UTF8 in s:
        s = s[bom_len:]

    return s.decode()

try:
    with open(filepath, encoding='utf-8-sig') as file_object:
        for line in file_object:
            line = line.rstrip()
            line = remove_bom(line)
            if line != '':
                print([line[0]])
except FileNotFoundError:
    print('No file found at ' + filepath)
```

Comment: read the file as a binary string, count how many boms there are, then remove that many bytes * 3 from the start of the string.

Comment: i might be misunderstanding: that would return multiple BOMs *all* at the beginning of a file? this file has BOMs sprinkled throughout.

Answer (score 0):

I'm having similar problems.
This kinda helped me:

```
import codecs
with open(path, "rb") as infile:
    bytecontent = infile.read()
bytecontent = bytecontent.replace(codecs.BOM_UTF8, b"")
```